# Adding a multidimensional numpy array into one array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a **multidimensional** numpy array that has the **shape (5, 6192, 1)** so essentially 5 arrays of length 6192 into one array.

How could I add the elements of all the arrays into one array of length 6192 in the following way.
For example if the 5 arrays look like

```
ar1 = [1,2,3...]
ar2 = [1,2,3...]
ar3 = [1,2,3...]
ar4 = [1,2,3...]
ar5 = [1,2,3...]
```

I want my final array to look like:

```
ar = [5,10,15,...]
```

So for each inner array, add the values of each same position into a new value for the final array that is the sum of all the values in this position.

The shape should be, I guess shape(1,6192,1).

Comment: Your input is unclear, do you have a list of lists? list of arrays? multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, simply use `numpy.sum`:

```
ar1 = [1,2,3]
ar2 = [1,2,3]
ar3 = [1,2,3]
ar4 = [1,2,3]
ar5 = [1,2,3]

arrays = [ar1, ar2, ar3, ar4, ar5]

ar = np.sum(arrays, axis=0)
```

output: `array([ 5, 10, 15])`

If really the shapes you describe are correct:

```
arr = np.array(arrays).reshape((5, 3, 1))
print(arr.shape)
# (5, 3, 1)

ar = np.sum(arr, axis=0)[None,:]

print(ar.shape)
# (1, 3, 1)
```